# How to create a full width site (Page Content container)

Tags: master-page, custom-masterpage

I am trying to create a page where the **page content** container takes up the 100% of the page. I tried looking at the v4.Master file but I couldn't figure out where or what to do.

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the desired look you can use the Oslo master page that exists by default in SharePoint 2013 and Office 365.
To change the master you will need to activate the publishing features if you are using collaboration sites, and you will need to use a custom css to remove the extra margins.

```
.contentwrapper {
margin: 0;
}

#titleAreaBox {
margin: auto 20px!important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joao! it works! any idea how to do it with the Seattle Master page? can I use the same css?

Answer (score 0):

```
#sideNavBox {display: none;}#contentBox {margin-left: 20px;}
```

add this css style and you can hide left site content. also make sure you are making changes in the selected master page.

Answer (score 0):

The white space occupied by is actually QuickLaunch area, you may update masterpage and remove quick launch snippet navigation, or if you can't edit masterpage, you may look through inspector of browser and add display none for the selector and give main content 100% width.